# Django DB table names, plural double s

Tags: python, django, django-models, grammar

In Rails when creating DB tables from the models, **Product** becomes **Products**, **Status** becomes **Statuses** etc. Django does not fully seem to have that inbuilt grammar functionality.
**Product** becomes **Products**, but **Status** becomes **Statuss**.

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, there's an attributes you can add to a models class Meta, `verbose_name_plural` -

```
class YourModel(Model):
    # fields
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Statuses'
```

See the [docs.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#verbose-name-plural)